# Ajax simples para recarregar um DIV a cada 30 segundos

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou o seguinte javascript para recarregar um `div` a cada 30 segundos, mas não está funcionando , nem apresenta erro.

Código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $div_novospedidos = $('#div_novospedidos');
    $div_novospedidos.empty(); //Limpando a tabela
    //setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 30000);
    setTimeout(newRequests(), 30000);


    function newRequests() {
        //$div_novospedidos.load("database3.php", function(data, status){
        $.get("database3.php", function(data, status) {
            var dados_pedido = data;
            const obj = dados_pedido;

            function executa_new() {
                try {
                    var dados = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(dados);
                    $.each(dados, function(i, item) {
                        numeroPedido = item.doc_number;
                        nomeCliente = item.client_name;
                        horarioPedido = item.clock;
                        var newReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 ">');
                        var cols = "";
                        cols += '<p>HORARIO: ' + horarioPedido + '</p></div>';
                        cols += '<p>PEDIDO: ' + numeroPedido + '</p></div>';
                        cols += '<p>Cliente: ' + nomeCliente + '</p></div>';
                        newReq.append(cols);
                        $("#div_novospedidos").append(newReq);
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro durante a chamada ' + e);
                    } else {
                        var zeroReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 "><h1>SEM NOVOS PEDIDOS</h1>');
                        $("#div_novospedidos").append(zeroReq);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {
                alert("SEM PEDIDOS");
            } else {
                executa_new();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Só tem uma chamada ao `setTimeout` logo nunca será a cada 30 segundos, e está a utilizar `if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {` fora da função `executa_new()` onde o `dados` é definido.

Comment: e qual seria correção  ?

Comment: Troque o `setTimeout` por `setInterval` pra ver no que dá. Não entendi o porquê de uma função dentro da outra.

Comment: Também não consegui perceber a ideia da função `executa_new` dentro do ajax se ela não é executada de imediato nem guardada numa variável. Melhor seria remover essa função e deixar só o código que ela tem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve aplicar o intervalo pretendido de forma **síncrona**, ou seja, chamar a função `newRequests()` apenas após o retorno do Ajax. Do jeito que está fazendo, pode sobrecarregar seu servidor e até mesmo travar o navegador.

Portanto, adicione um `setTimeout()` após o retorno do Ajax dentro da função que você quer chamar novamente.

*Outra coisa é separar as funções. Cada função tem uma aplicação própria, e neste caso, é melhor deixá-las separadas.*

Seu código ficaria assim.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $div_novospedidos = $('#div_novospedidos');
    $div_novospedidos.empty(); //Limpando a tabela
    newRequests();
});

function newRequests() {
    //$div_novospedidos.load("database3.php", function(data, status){
    $.get("database3.php", function(data, status) {
        var dados_pedido = data;
        const obj = dados_pedido;

        setTimeout("newRequests()", 30000);

        if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {
            alert("SEM PEDIDOS");
        } else {
            executa_new();
        }
    });
}

function executa_new() {
    try {
        var dados = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(dados);
        $.each(dados, function(i, item) {
            numeroPedido = item.doc_number;
            nomeCliente = item.client_name;
            horarioPedido = item.clock;
            var newReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 ">');
            var cols = "";
            cols += '<p>HORARIO: ' + horarioPedido + '</p></div>';
            cols += '<p>PEDIDO: ' + numeroPedido + '</p></div>';
            cols += '<p>Cliente: ' + nomeCliente + '</p></div>';
            newReq.append(cols);
            $("#div_novospedidos").append(newReq);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {
            alert('Ocorreu um erro durante a chamada ' + e);
        } else {
            var zeroReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 "><h1>SEM NOVOS PEDIDOS</h1>');
            $("#div_novospedidos").append(zeroReq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nao funcionou , entrou em loop preenchendo os divs com as informacoes erradas.

Comment: @RodrigoBravo Esqueci de colocar a função no `setTimeout` entre aspas, assim: `setTimeout("newRequests()", 30000);`. Veja agora.

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando a função `setTimeout` que é uma função que coloca um tempo maximo de exceução para uma determinada função, pelo que entendi você deseja que sua função seja executada mais de uma vez, neste caso o comando correto é `setInterval`

Ficando assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $div_novospedidos = $('#div_novospedidos');
    $div_novospedidos.empty(); //Limpando a tabela
    //setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 30000);
    setInterval(newRequests(), 30000);


    function newRequests() {
        //$div_novospedidos.load("database3.php", function(data, status){
        $.get("database3.php", function(data, status) {
            var dados_pedido = data;
            const obj = dados_pedido;

            function executa_new() {
                try {
                    var dados = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(dados);
                    $.each(dados, function(i, item) {
                        numeroPedido = item.doc_number;
                        nomeCliente = item.client_name;
                        horarioPedido = item.clock;
                        var newReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 ">');
                        var cols = "";
                        cols += '<p>HORARIO: ' + horarioPedido + '</p></div>';
                        cols += '<p>PEDIDO: ' + numeroPedido + '</p></div>';
                        cols += '<p>Cliente: ' + nomeCliente + '</p></div>';
                        newReq.append(cols);
                        $("#div_novospedidos").append(newReq);
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro durante a chamada ' + e);
                    } else {
                        var zeroReq = $('<div class="panel panel-default col-6 col-lg-4 "><h1>SEM NOVOS PEDIDOS</h1>');
                        $("#div_novospedidos").append(zeroReq);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (typeof dados != 'undefined') {
                alert("SEM PEDIDOS");
            } else {
                executa_new();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**Um pouco mais sobre as funções:**

São duas funções interessantes do Javascript, com elas podemos definir um intervalo de tempo que um evento irá acontecer.

A sintaxe das duas funções é praticamente idêntica. O que muda é como agem.

Sintaxe:

```
window.setTimeout('funcao()', intervalo_em_milisegundos);
window.setInterval('funcao()', intervalo_em_milisegundos);
```

As duas funções irão chamar uma segunda função passada por parâmetro no intervalo determinado também por parâmetro.

Sendo a setTimeout() chamando a função uma única vez. Enquanto a setInterval() chama a função “infinitamente” sempre no mesmo intervalo de tempo.

Para pausar a função usa-se `clearInterval()`. Passando como parâmetro o nome do seu intervalo.

Ex:

```
var intervalo = window.setInterval(lerolero, 1000);
function lerolero() {
    window.alert("Popup");
}
clearInterval(intervalo);
```

Fonte: http://rogeriolino.com/2006/12/19/javascript-settimeout-e-setinterval/

Comment: aparentemente a funcao nao esta executando novamente depois de 30seg, coloquei um alert para ter certeza , e nao executa novamente ....

Comment: Você consegue me dar mais detalhes, testei aqui e tudo certo.

Comment: por exemplo, coloquei um alert("teste"); na funcao newRequests, com o setInterval da forma que voce sugeriu, se fecho esse alert, quando funcao executar novamente, ele nao deveria reabrir ?